# Question about the composite of a homeomorphism and a continuous onto function.

Tags: general-topology, function-and-relation-composition

If $f : (G,T)$ homeomorphically to $(A,T_1)$, and $h: (A,T_1)$ continuously and onto $(C,T_2)$, then is it always the case that, given the composition $g = h \circ f : (G,T) \rightarrow (C,T_3)$, the continuous onto image of $G = C$?  Or $g(G) = C$?

I'm a little confused because I thought that the composite of two bijective functions did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Homeomorphisms are surjective by definition, so
$$g(G)=h(f(G))=h(A)=C.$$
Also, a composition of continuous functions is always continuous.

Comment: So for functions in general:  If $f : A \rightarrow B$, then: $Rng(f) = \{b \in B: \exists x \in A, f(x) = y\} = f(A) = \{f(x) : x \in A\}$?  And a function is surjective iff $Rng(f) = f(A) = B$?

Comment: @OliverG Yes, that's right.